# Hazelcast Eviction mechanism

Tags: hazelcast

I have a question about Hazelcast eviction mechanism, I configured 'Least Recently Used' in combination with 'Free Heap Percentage' and deliberately configured JVM size to a small value (128MB)...

Now I place a middle sized Java Object to the Map and I observe that around 1400 Objects being started to Evicted. I placed the objects with id equal to iteration number and while I used LRU policy, I was expecting the entries will be evicted from 1 to 2000 but it seems it complete random. Am I missing some thing here?

Secondly, how many records will be actually evicted, until eviction mechanism achieve again %30 Free Heap space? or some thing else?

Thx for answers...

Comment: Map eviction is explained in detail here: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11.2/manual/html-single/index.html#map-eviction

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you are storing: size of java objects, number of objects stored before eviction starts, eviction-percentage and size of JVM heap?

Comment: In between I started to understand the problem better, Hazelcast uses following method to find potential candidates for eviction 'protected Iterable<EntryView> getSamples(RecordStore recordStore) {
        Storage storage = recordStore.getStorage();
        return (Iterable<EntryView>) storage.getRandomSamples(SAMPLE_COUNT);
    }' SAMPLE_COUNT being 'int DEFAULT_SAMPLE_COUNT = 15 int SAMPLE_COUNT = getInteger(SYSTEM_PROPERTY_SAMPLE_COUNT, DEFAULT_SAMPLE_COUNT);' so it picks randomly 15 datasets and then compare those with 'mapEvictionPolicy.compare(candidate, selected)'

Comment: LRUEvictionPolicy being 'public int compare(EntryView entryView1, EntryView entryView2) {
        long lastAccessTime1 = entryView1.getLastAccessTime();
        long lastAccessTime2 = entryView2.getLastAccessTime();
        return (lastAccessTime1 < lastAccessTime2) ? -1 : ((lastAccessTime1 == lastAccessTime2) ? 0 : 1);
    }' so it compares the 'lastAccessTime' of 15 random dataset so actually there can be other datasets in the system with older 'lastAccessTime' but still not evicted.